How to fix git merge-base failing?
I want to be able to run this command:
git diff --name-only HEAD $(git merge-base HEAD remotes/origin/dev)

The git merge-base command is failing and returning nothing--no error or anything. The branch was created off of the dev branch, so there is a common commit between the two. How do I figure out why this command is failing and how to get it to work?
The command works on my local computer but not in this other environment.
To troubleshoot, I ran the following commands on both my local computer and the other environment:
My computer:
> git branch
* myBranch
> git show-ref remotes/origin/dev
6f5795fc6932784342adda78e2507a537beb72c3 refs/remotes/origin/dev
> git show-ref -h HEAD
2fd86bdba9eee8a7041045c96e0d37b3e7d28906 HEAD
6f5795fc6932784342adda78e2507a537beb72c3 refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
> git symbolic-ref HEAD
refs/heads/myBranch
> git rev-parse HEAD
2fd86bdba9eee8a7041045c96e0d37b3e7d28906
> git merge-base HEAD remotes/origin/dev
63ed7a1acdb477a37acba3cc1cdec33048adb260
> git diff --name-only HEAD $(git merge-base HEAD remotes/origin/dev)
myFile.xml

Other environment:
> git branch
* myBranch
> git show-ref remotes/origin/dev
6f5795fc6932784342adda78e2507a537beb72c3 refs/remotes/origin/dev
> git show-ref -h HEAD
2fd86bdba9eee8a7041045c96e0d37b3e7d28906 HEAD
> git symbolic-ref HEAD
refs/heads/myBranch
> git rev-parse HEAD
2fd86bdba9eee8a7041045c96e0d37b3e7d28906
> git merge-base HEAD remotes/origin/dev
# exit code 1
> git diff --name-only HEAD $(git merge-base HEAD remotes/origin/dev)
# returns nothing

What's wrong in the other environment? Should I have cloned it differently? Different git config settings?

Can you prove, using a GUI, that HEAD and origin/dev have a common ancestor? Because I tend to believe Git; the extraordinary claim that Git is mistaken needs extraordinary proof.

I agree.... I would bet money there is a problem with the assumptions, not git. An easy explanation, perhaps: did history of one of the branches get rewritten?

@matt The commands work fine with the same branches on my local computer but they're not working in a container in my CI/CD workflow. I updated my question with the commands and results.

@eftshift0 that's entirely possible, but I don't know enough about git to figure out what exactly is the problem and how to fix it

git show-ref doesn't show HEAD by default,you have to ask for it with -h /  --head. Some advice from an old hand: slow your roll, you're not checking docs and evidence carefully enough when confused. You're showing each step, that's good, very good, even, but you're not checking at each step whether what you saw was exactly what you expected to see, and why you expected that.

@jthill ok with the -h the git show-ref is now returning a value and not failing

Check history of both branches by hand (with gitk, for example)... you will be shocked to find that they are not actually related (commit-wise, that is... which is what git considers when doing git merge-base).

That kind of issue may happen when you have a shallow clone to start with -- and that's the default setup for many CI/CD pipelines (GitHub, gitlab, Azure DevOps...).

To confirm the issue:
check if the following git log commands show the complete history of the branches, or if one history is truncated at some point:
git log --graph --oneline myBranch
git log --graph --oneline origin/dev


To fix the issue:
use git fetch --unshallow, for example:
git fetch --unshallow origin myBranch


Even better, perhaps, would be git log --graph --oneline myBranch origin/dev, i.e. graph both branches and see whether they meet. This is the kind of thing I meant by "prove using a GUI" in my initial comment.

@matt: I agree, I just thought it would be easier to spot which ref was truncated by checking the 2 histories separately.

@LeGEC thanks! With git log I was able to see that the origin/dev branch apparently didn't have the whole history so git fetch --unshallow fixed my issue

@jeremywat: check the options of your ci pipeline configuration, there propably is an option about "shallow" or "fetch depth" or some similar term which activates (or deactivates) the initial shallow clone.

Yeah I removed the depth option so it shouldn't be doing a shallow clone, I don't know why it still did

Oh on second thought it looks like it might have a default depth of 1, which is probably what happened.
